# How can I open a haskell file (.hs) in Mac?

Tags: macos, haskell

I already installed haskell from [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html).
I can use haskell from my terminal by typing `ghci` but I don't know how to open my .hs files.

Comment: `:load YourHaskellFile.hs`?

Comment: Thats the answer, should I close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just normal text files; use whichever text editor you use for other languages.

If you want to load it into `ghci`, use `:l file.hs` or `:load file.hs`

Comment: Yeah I can do that but I want to open these archives with the Haskell compiler

Comment: If you want to compile your program, you must use `ghc` from the command line. They are normal text files, not archives. For loading into ghci, see @leftroundabout's comment

Comment: To be clear: I don't believe there is a single compiler that has any concept of "opening" a file for a user.  The compiler can compile the source file (.hs) into an object file.

Comment: I got it, so should I close this question?

Comment: Hope it helps future new haskell users on Mac